# MIPS: why is ISR surrounded with rdpgpr $sp, $sp; wrpgpr $sp, $sp instructions?

Tags: mips, isr

I'm working with PIC32 MCUs (MIPS M4K core), I'm trying to understand how do interrupts work in MIPS; I'm armed with "See MIPS Run" book, official MIPS reference and Google. No one of them can help me understand the following:

I have interrupt declared like this:

```
void __ISR(_CORE_TIMER_VECTOR) my_int_handler(void)
```

I look at disassembly, and I see that `RDPGPR SP, SP` is called in the ISR prologue (first instruction, actually); and balancing `WRPGPR SR, SR` instruction is called in the ISR epilogue (before writing previously-saved `Status` register to CP0 and calling `ERET`).
I see that these instruction purposes are to read from and save to previous shadow register set, so, `RDPGPR SP, SP` reads `$sp` from shadow register set and `WRPGPR SR, SR` writes it back, but I can't understand the reason for this. This ISR intended not to use shadow register set, and actually in disassembly I see that context is saved to the stack. But, for some reason, `$sp` is read from and written to shadow `$sp`. Why is this?

And, related question: is there some really comprehensive resource (book, or something) on MIPS assembly language? "See MIPS Run" seems really good, it's great starting point for me to dig into MIPS architecture, but it does not cover several topics good enough, several things off the top of my head:

- Very little information about EIC (external interrupt controller) mode: it has the diagram with `Cause` register that shows that in EIC mode we have `RIPL` instead of `IP7-2`, but there is nothing about how does it work (say, that interrupt is caused if only `Cause->RIPL` is more than `Status->IPL`. There's even no explanation what `RIPL` does mean ("Requested Interrupt Priority Level", well, Google helped). I understand that EIC is implementation-dependent, but the things I just mentioned are generic.
- Assembly language is covered not completely enough: say, nothing about macro (`.macro`, `.endm` directives), I couldn't find anything about some assembler directives I've seen in the existing code, say, `.set mips32r2`, and so on.
- I cant find anything about using `rdpgpr`/`wrpgpr` in the ISR, it covers these instructions (and shadow register sets in general) very briefly

Official MIPS reference doesn't help much in these topics as well. Is there really good book that covers all possible assembly directives, and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the MIPS core enters an ISR it can swap the interrupted code's active register set with a new one (there can be several different shadow register sets), specific for that interrupt priority.

Usually the interrupt routines don't have a stack of their own, and because the just switched-in shadow register set certainly have its sp register with a different value than the interrupted code's, the ISR copies the sp value from the just switched-out shadow register set to its own, to be able to use the interrupted code's stack.

If you wish, you could set your ISR's stack to a previously allocated stack of its own, but that is usually not useful.